# PostgreSQL row to string

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, null, row

I have a result from a query like the below, which does not have a fixed number of columns

```
ID  COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
-------------------------------------
1   VAL11   VAL12   VAL13   VAL14
2   VAL21   VAL22   VAL23   VAL24
```

Now I want the result to be something like this.

```
RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------
ID:1, COL1:VAL11, COL2:VAL12, COL3:VAL13, COL4:VAL14
ID:2, COL1:VAL21, COL2:VAL22, COL3:VAL23, COL4:VAL24
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and dirty way, but without the column names and including NULL values:

```
SELECT tbl::text
FROM   tbl;
```

The slow & sure way:

```
SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY[
          'ID:'   || id
         ,'COL1:' || col1
         ,'COL2:' || col2
        ], ', ')  AS result
FROM    tbl;
```

If a column holds a `NULL` value, it will be missing in the result. I do not just concatenate, because `NULL` values would nullify the whole row.
[`array_to_string()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) makes sure that commas are only inserted where needed.

---

PostgreSQL **9.1** introduced the new function [**`concat_ws()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) (much like the one in MySQL) with which we can further simplify:

```
SELECT concat_ws(', '
          'ID:'   || id
         ,'COL1:' || col1
         ,'COL2:' || col2
        ) AS result
FROM    tbl;
```

Comment: Wouldnt' the second way be much easier by simply concatenating the values instead of first creating an array, and than converting that array back to a string?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: How would you deal with `NULL` values then? You would need a `CASE` statement for every column and have a hard time to make the commas fit. Been there, done that. It's much easier this way. Without `NULL` values, you would be right, though.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `coalesce()` instead of a `CASE` statement to deal with `NULL`s?

Comment: @vyegorov: `COALESCE` or `CASE` are two tools to the same end. Placement of commas would be the tricky part. All possible but more complex than necessary. Try to supply a query for rows with multiple columns ...

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
            'ID:'  ||coalesce(id::text,   '<null>')
    ||', '||'COL1:'||coalesce(col1::text, '<null>')
    ||', '||'COL2:'||coalesce(col2::text, '<null>')
FROM tbl;
```

You can use this SQL to generate the first one for you (in case there're lot's of columns):

```
SELECT E'SELECT \n'||string_agg(trim(stmt), E' \n')||E'\n  FROM tbl;'
  FROM (SELECT
    CASE WHEN a.attnum > 1 THEN $$||', '||$$ ELSE '' END ||
    $$'$$||upper(a.attname)||$$:'||coalesce($$||quote_ident(a.attname)||
    $$::text, '<null>')$$ AS stmt
  FROM pg_attribute a, pg_class t
 WHERE t.relkind='r' AND t.relname = 'tbl' AND a.attrelid = t.oid
   AND NOT a.attisdropped AND a.attnum > 0) AS s;
```

Comment: If you substitute a placeholder for columns with NULLs it becomes simpler. The tricky part is to trim `NULL` columns. Suppose, the first column is NULL, or first and second ... Since pg 9.1 you can further simplify with `concat_ws()`.